# classes loaded by jvm

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I have a running jvm process and I want a tool to get classes loaded by that jvm, are there one?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `jmap -histo <PID>`

It'll show histogram of loaded classes including classname, number of instances, size, etc

Answer (score 4):

```
jinfo <pid>
```

will give you quite a bit information, including the classpath and the jars in the path.
see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jinfo.html)

The jinfo command may be limited by the permissions granted to the principal running the command. The command will only list the JVMs for which the principle has access rights as determined by operating system specific access control mechanisms.

Note also that jinfo is **not** available on windows or linux itanium.

Comment: I have tried it ([pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/tF8J0Phn)), and noting, what is wrong?

Comment: I've amended my info. You're on windows and so out of luck when it comes to jinfo. IMHO, use bot trojanfoe and Umesha Kacha:s answers

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following in the command line

```
java -verbose:class ....
```

and the JVM will dump out what it's loading including all its locations

Comment: it will put loaded classes into the standard output, so messing with program output isn't it? so how can I redirect it to some other location?

Answer (score 1):

try visual VM. It is free but is not distributed with JRE/JDK but you can download it from official oracle website. Also you can make a heap dump and than you can view it by standard tools from JDK.

Comment: VisualVM is distributed with (at least) the JDK, no manual download is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the process has [JMX enabled](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) then you can use `jvisualvm` (bundled with the JDK) to examine such properties.

Comment: There is nice tab Classes, but is it possible to see where each Class has come from (file path etc)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I don't if there is.